# img form with overlay function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I have a picture, which should open an overlay on click.

The overlay should be closed by a click as well.

I had an almost working version with a button, but the picture was shifted.

I tried a form function and it looks much better, but I only see the overlay flickering before it's disappearing. So the onclick function doesn't work anymore.

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overGeld").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overGeld").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
css: #overGeld {
  display: none;
  width: 380px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  margin-left: -50px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 130%;
}
```

```html
<div id="spendMö">
  <form class="bildbt" onclick="on()">
    <input type="image" class="bilder" id="geld" src="hund-geld.jpg">
  </form>
  <div id="overGeld" onclick="off()">
    <a>.....</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: input type="image" is a submit button - you need to use <button type="button" or a link with a preventDefault

Comment: Hi Laura, change input to img and everything will work as planned ;)

Answer (score 0):

`input type="image"` is a submit button -

you need to use `<img`or `<button type="button"` or a link with a preventDefault

```js
document.getElementById("spendMö").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let imgStyle = document.getElementById("overGeld").style;
  imgStyle.display = imgStyle.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
})
```

```css
#overGeld {
  display: none;
  width: 380px;
  height: 350px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  margin-left: -50px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 130%;
}
```

```html
<div id="spendMö">
  <img class="bilder" id="geld" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/helga1981/helga19811605/helga1981160500142/56492101-hund-in-den-gl%C3%A4sern-h%C3%A4lt-in-seine-pfoten-eine-menge-geld-isoliert-auf-wei%C3%9Fem-hintergrund.jpg">
  <div id="overGeld">
    Over Geld
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you over complicated Laura's code, her issue is with the element she's assign to toggle the display, not need to re-write it and add complexity to it the way you did in javascript

Comment: Ahem, no. I added event listener to extract the horrible multiple inline event handlers
If you remove the comments it is simpler

Comment: what would say about this `document.getElementById("overGeld").style.display = document.getElementById("overGeld").style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block"`

Comment: It's a toggle. I wanted to do classList.toggle but this was less complex

Comment: it's overly complicating and can be in a better way like like this 
`var overGeld = document.getElementById("overGeld");
overGeld.style.display = yourUl.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';` or even `
var overGeld = document.getElementById("overGeld");
var isShowing = overGeid.hidden
overGeld.hidden = !isShowing
`
as it's available on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden

Comment: The code you just posted is almost identical to mine except `yourUl` does not belong in the code

Comment: Also you cannot test === "none" if the display:none is in CSS only. Try it